# I'm trying to recreate queue using ArrayList in java but am having troubles

Tags: java, arraylist, queue

I'm giving a sample .txt file. In this file, the first 2 integers in the first line is the amount of Primary Servers and Secondary Servers there are working at a fast food restaurant. For the rest of the line, 1st integer is customer arrival time, 2nd integer is time primary server takes to serve, 3rd integer is time secondary server takes to serve. (In this case primary servers can be seen as counter server and secondary server can be seen as cook).

3   2

3   2   7

4   11  2

7   14  7

12  3   18

14  8   2

I have created classes for Server, Queue and Customer.

I have pasted the main logic of my code here:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < primaryServers.size(); i++) {
                Server primaryServer = primaryServers.get(i);

                if (!primaryServer.isBusy() && !priQueue.qIsEmpty()) {
                    Customer customer = priQueue.dequeue();
                    primaryServer.startService(customer.getPriQueueTime());
                    primaryServer.incrementQueueCount();
                    primaryServer.updateTotalServiceTime(customer.getPriQueueTime());
                    secQueue.enqueue(customer);
                }

                primaryServer.decreaseServiceTime();

                if (!primaryServer.isBusy()) {
                    primaryServer.incrementIdleTime();
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < secondaryServers.size(); i++) {
                Server secondaryServer = secondaryServers.get(i);

                if (!secondaryServer.isBusy() && !secQueue.qIsEmpty()) {
                    Customer customer = secQueue.dequeue();
                    secondaryServer.startService(customer.getSecQueueTime());
                    secondaryServer.incrementQueueCount();
                    secondaryServer.updateTotalServiceTime(customer.getSecQueueTime());
                }

                secondaryServer.decreaseServiceTime();
                servedCustomers++;

                if (!secondaryServer.isBusy()) {
                    secondaryServer.incrementIdleTime();
                }
            }

            currentTime++;

        }
```

This is the code for the output:

```
 System.out.println("--- Server Data ---");

        for(int i = 0; i < primaryServers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s", "P" + (i + 1));
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (Server p : primaryServers) {

            System.out.printf("%-15d", p.getTotalServiceTime());

        }
        System.out.println("Serve Time (in minutes.)");
        for (Server p : primaryServers) {

            System.out.printf("%-15d", p.getIdleTime());

        }

        System.out.println("Idle Time (in minutes.)\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < secondaryServers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s", "S" + (i + 1));
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (Server s : secondaryServers) {

            System.out.printf("%-15d", s.getTotalServiceTime());

        }
        System.out.println("Serve Time (in minutes.)");
        for (Server s : secondaryServers) {

            System.out.printf("%-15d", s.getIdleTime());

        }
        System.out.println("Idle Time (in minutes.)\n");
```

This is the result I get.
--- Server Data ---
P1             P2             P3
0              0              0              Serve Time (in minutes.)
3              3              3              Idle Time (in minutes.)

S1             S2
0              0              Serve Time (in minutes.)
3              3              Idle Time (in minutes.)

I'm not sure why the data is not being passed into the queue even though I wrote the enqueue and dequeue myself

```
    public void enqueue(Customer customer) {
        customerQueueList.add(customer);
            customerInQueue++;
            totalCountCustomers++;

    }

    public Customer dequeue() {
        if (!customerQueueList.isEmpty()) {
            customerInQueue--;
            return customerQueueList.remove(0); // Remove and return the first customer
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Initially I was using an enhanced for-loop to loop through the primary servers and secondary servers to enqueue and dequeue them. I thought it might be unsure who was busy and who is not so I changed it to a normal for-loop for them to loop through every server but nothing I've tried worked.

Comment: *I'm trying to recreate queue using ArrayList* **Why?** [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is built-in. Note: [*The name deque is short for "double ended queue" and is usually pronounced "deck".*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

Comment: I have an assignment that is testing my understanding of queues so we are not allowed to use the built in queue function. We have to build it our own.